# Phing - how to checkout from svn, then upload via ftp and chmod directories

Tags: php, svn, build, ftp, phing

I have been reading the Phing documentation and it makes sense, but I'm not able to find out from there or on Google (or here) how to do what I would consider to be a fairly normal build procedure - checkout from svn, then upload the checked out copy via ftp and then chmod certain directories (for uploading files).

Is this possible with Phing, or would I have to write my own task class to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible? Sure, *anything* is possible - given enough time and resources. You can also extend Phing with your own tasks if it doesn't yet cover what you want.

But regarding your specific question : to checkout from svn use the svncheckout (or svnexport - the latter seems more appropriate for your scenario) task, to transfer with ftp use the ftpdeploy task (or better yet - use scp instead of ftp), and to chmod some files you could use the ssh task (provided that you have SSH access of course).

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at Phing: Wow, it does look a lot like Ant.

You need to look at the Optional Tasks in [Appendix C](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/appendixes/AppendixC-OptionalTasks.html). There, you'll see a bunch of `svn` tasks, and the `scp` task that can copy files from one system to another. Worse comes to worse, you can use the `exec` task to call the command line `ftp` command. With that, you can define `.netrc` file that will automatically login and transfer files.

They have a sample [build file](http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/), but I don't know Phing, so I'm not going to try to write one.